# Porting Qt code to C (POST using libcurl)

Tags: qt, http-post, libcurl

Currently I am porting Qt code to C.

Qt code:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
QByteArray data;
QNetworkRequest request;

mainReply = manager->post(request, data); //What is the equivalent in libcurl?
connect(mainReply, SIGNAL(finished()),   this, SLOT(get_imghttpFinished()));
```

I want to port the same code to C using libcurl. 
Can anyone suggest the equivalent function for "manager->post"?

Comment: I assume `**mainReply = manager->post(request, data);**` is to emphasize that line? Don't do that in your code. Put a comment after it perhaps. But bolding won't work and only serves to confuse.

Comment: Yes it is to emphasize that line.

Comment: I've edited it to a comment. `**mainReply` suggests something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

In that line, QNetworkAccessManager does a simple POST request. According to the curl documentation, you can do something like this to replace this code:

```
char *data="name=daniel&project=curl";
curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://posthere.com/");
curl_easy_perform(easyhandle);
```

These links might help you, there is the documentation for the C binding of curl (see chapter HTTP POSTing in the first link) and an example of doing a POST request with curl in C.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html

Hope this helped :)

EDIT: it seems that you can send a file with `curl_formadd` [function](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html), without having to read it previously.

```
curl_formadd(&post, &last, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "picture",   CURLFORM_FILE, "my-face.jpg", CURLFORM_END);
```

Comment: Is it possible to send binary data(image data) in this without encoding?

Comment: I think so yes, the solution would depend on what you're using to read the image.

Comment: Image data shall be transferred by using the following functions 
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, fdata);
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, size);